Databricks Merge on multiple columns
The following Databricks SQL query will allow me to merge on a single column from a single database
 CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP VIEW rs AS
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rand()) AS seq
    FROM basef1area.drivers;
    
    MERGE INTO basef1area.races AS t
    USING rs
    ON t.race_ID = rs.seq
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE SET t.reject_reason = rs.driver_ID;

Can someone let me know how to modify the query that will allow to use another database table (basef1area.circuits) to merge on an additional column, such that the UPDATE SET clause would something like:
UPDATE SET t.reject_reason = rs.driver_ID;
UPDATE SET t.race_name= rs.driver_ref;


To update multiple columns on merge:
MERGE INTO basef1area.races AS t
    USING rs
    ON t.race_ID = rs.seq
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE SET t.reject_reason = rs.driver_ID,
                 t.race_name= rs.driver_ref;

Or, if you want to update all fields:
MERGE INTO basef1area.races AS t
    USING rs
    ON t.race_ID = rs.seq
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE SET *


thanks for reaching out. Your suggestion would work, have it doesn't appear to take into account the driver_ref comes from table basef1area.circuits and driver_ID comes from basef1area.circuits

@Patterson , I'm not sure what is the join between circuits an drivers. You can add the join to the creation of the temp view, and then use it in the merge command.
